# Validate id exists ignored in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase to add Users. I also have a Newuser, which is an empty user that can be initialised using an id (the id's come from tags I already made).

Now when a **newuser** is initialised, Firebase should check if the given tagid is already used in the users table (as a key).

This is what my **Users** and **NewUser** data looks like;

[image]

This is the Firebase Rule I'm applying **which is working in the simulator**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "newuser": {
      "tagid": {
        ".validate": "root.child('users/'+newData.val()).val() === null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason I'm able to add this newuser record, using an existing tagid using the Firebase REST API. (with Postman)

Comment: Are you using the admin API to create the data? If so, rules are ignored by the admin API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I'm using the following guide: I don't think it's the admin API, right? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Comment: No, you're right. Can you include the request you're sending?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794709/firebase-validate-with-newdata?rq=1

Comment: The only data I'm inclusing is {"tagid": 3}. Thank you i'll take a look at the other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules you've configured don't quite match the database structure you're working with, so you'll need to try something more like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "newuser": {
      "$pushid" : {
        ".validate": "root.child('users/'+newData.child('tagid').val()).val() === null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above rules, the `$pushid` value will match any key at `/newuser/$pushid` (for example, your key of `-KxhGb7zZy8cZM5Pkntz`), and then using `newData.child('tagid')` will obtain the `tagid` value from that new data.

Using a `$location` value in the rules is like a wildcard variable, so it will automatically match any node name at that location. From the [`$location` rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location):

> A variable that can be used to reference the key of a `$location` that was used earlier in a rule structure.
>
> When you have a `$location` in your rules structure, you can use a matching `$` variable within your rule expression to get the name of the actual child being read or written.

This is required with your current structure, because when you're adding to your `newuser` node, your payload looks something like this:

```
{
    "newuser" {
        "$pushId": {
            "tagid": int
        }
    }
}
```

You can test your rules in the [Rules Simulator in the Firebase database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/rules). In my tests of this, the write was denied when I had `/users/1` already in the database and my payload included the value of `tagid: 1`:

[image: simulator screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do you get that $pushid in the database rules tester?

Comment: @Notflip Using a `$location` value in the rules is like a wildcard variable, so it will match any node name at that location automatically. I've added this clarification to my answer.

Comment: I'd love to know the reason behind someone's recent downvote of this answer so that I can improve it...

Comment: that's odd your answer explains it perfectly and is well structured.